# How can I create a web app in Flask that provides feedback to the user about the progress of a Celery task?

Tags: python, flask, celery, server-sent-events

I am new to web app programming in general, and flask in particular.  I am trying to create a "graphical" interface to some Python code I wrote a while ago.  It was suggested to me that instead of writing a graphical interface I should make it a web app with flask.  The code I want it to run may take a while and I also want the user to be able to run multiple instances concurrently.  I was told I should use celery for the concurrency.

Another major requirement is that feedback about the progress should be given to the user.  Not knowing much about web programming from the start I did a bit of research to figure out how this can be done on the web and discovered server-sent events which seemed perfect to me.  Trying to figure out how to do this in Flask, I found http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/116/ which I got to work as described.  After learning about celery and getting the example at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/celery/ to work, I tried creating a simple example of a task that would have some sort of state that would update over time and feed that back to the user.  The problem I ran into was that my celery tasks didn't seem to start.

I then found an example where server-sent events were used in a chat program that used redis, so I thought I would try that, but I had the same result.  Below is what I wrote to implement the subscribe functionality:

```
@flask_app.route("/subscribe", methods=['GET'])
def subscribe():
    targetname = request.args['target']
    print 'The subscribe function was called with target: ' + targetname
    return Response(buildSubscription(targetname), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

I then have a celery task:

```
@celery.task()
def testPrint(printfunc,initvalue):
    print "In testPrint"
    x=hashlib.md5(initvalue)
    i=0
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        printfunc(x.hexdigest())
        x.update(str(i))
        i+=1
```

where celery is set by the `make_celery` function.  I then have a function:

```
def ssePrint(mystring,sub):
    print "In ssePrint"
    red.pubsub(sub,mystring)
```

and a wrapper for that function:

```
def appPrint(subscription):
    sub = subscription

    def myprint(myinput):
        ssePrint(myinput, sub)

    return myprint
```

which is then called in

```
@flask_app.route('/start', methods=['POST'])
def start():
    myobject = request.get_json()
    testPrint.delay(appPrint(myobject['target']), myobject['target'])
```

When I then look at the shell that invoked celery, I do not see any tasks running.  This happens when I also use gevent.Queue as described in the SSE Flask example.

My suspicion is that there might be an issue with communicating from a Celery task to something running outside of the task.  Is there a standard way of extracting the kind of information I want from a Celery task?  Should I consider another way of doing concurrency?

Thanks.